# Purple leaves on Tomato?

Tags: diagnosis, tomatoes

[image]
I have six tomato plants pair of 2 in 3 pots. All of my tomato plants are having purple leaves due to which the plant is not growing well. I have also added vermicompost. Then ,Why is it so ?
Is it due to the cold weather or it is because I have planted 2 plants in a single pot ?
Plz help me with a solution?

Comment: My first thought is potassium deficiency: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=tomato+potassium+deficiency+symptoms&t=ffsb&iax=images&ia=images and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_deficiency_(plants) It's an odd thing to have, if you are fertilizing. Might well be something else; hence, not an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Its cold. This coloration happens when the plant is exposed to cold and light at the same time. The cold roots cannot take up phosphate properly.

If you want to do an experiment, protect just some from the very coldest conditions and report what happens.

Purple leaves can also be caused by phytoplasma infection, unlikely in this case. Spread by sucking insects.

Phosphate deficiency causes purple leaves in tomato too, but that affects the older leaves.

Comment: Should I keep the plants inside the house till the weather gets better ?

Comment: I am not sure, mostly because I dont know the temperatures involved. Even a few hours in a less-cold place might help. why not take a couple of plants inside for a day and see? Perfect conditions to try experimenting. Dont cook them!

Answer (score 3):

For me it is because the half broken stem. You see that the weight of the tomatoes fold the stem, and so the nutrients have more difficult to flow.

You should always tie the tomatoes plants to the support: the fruits are so heavy (compared to the plant), that you have such problems.

If I'm correct, the purple leaves are just after the bended stem.

On the other hand, the bottom side of the leaves may have some sign of mites, which could cause purple leaves.  could you check the bottom side, and possibly add a photo?

Comment: But brother all the other plants are also having purple leaves and none of their stems are bended.

Answer (score 2):

Purple & red leaves on tomatoes (& many other green leaf plants) are in indication of stress.  Without having an onsite knowledge of your plant, your habits & your weather it would be hard for me to give you an exact answer.  I will make a list of some of the reason.  Starting with the most likely;

cool or cold weather,

allowing the soil to dry out (two plants will cause this more often),

lack of the correct nutrients (two plants will cause to happen more often. Use tomato fertiliser or fertiliser high in phosphorous, calcium & magnesium),

hot weather,

soil is water logged

[SFGate Purple Leaves on Tomato Plants](https://homeguides.sfgate.com/causes-tomato-plants-purple-41716.html)